# C помощью каких инструментов можно передавать контент во фрагмент?

Tags: java, android, json, api, retrofit

Есть задумка, далеко не новая, но интересна в самой реализации.

Есть блог(на wordpress) при добавлении новости, автоматически(с помощью плагина) новость дублируется в vk.

И собственно вопрос, как подобное реализовать, но уже в android app.
Создать фрагмент, в него запихнуть recyclerView и с помощью JSON попытаться или же лучше с retrofit? С обоими способами знаком заочно, а потому не уверен, что такое *возможно*(знаю что возможно :) ). Интересно было услышать Ваше мнение, возможно даже полезные ссылки с подобными примерами.

Comment: retrofit и JSON  - не противоположные вещи, я при помощи retrofit очень даже просто работаю с JSON. Точнее, retrofit работает вместо меня, отдавая сразу модель данных.

Comment: Заголовок вашего вопроса не совпадает с самим вопросом.

Comment: @metalurgus на сколько я понимаю не проблема сделать несколько разных фрагментов и туда передавать контент с разных категорий?

Comment: Если контент одного и того же формата, то можно использовать один класс, но загружать разные данные

Comment: @metalurgus ну то есть context + image скажем в recyclerView виднеется. Ну а если в самой статье предположим несколько картинок(когда выбираешь пункт из recycler'a) то тогда как быть? или не имеет значение сколько их, главное что формата image все?

Comment: Я не понял ничего из пиредыдущего комментария

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Короче создаешь `Fragment` в него RecyclerView. Данные получаешь с OkHttp либо Retrofit исходя из того, что будет удобнее. Данные скоре всего будут в JSON, можно в XML, но в JSON попроще будет.

Получать значения можно через `OkHttp`, можно через `Retrofit` (который этот же `OkHttp` использует сам). Вопрос в том как написано API. Если там у вас модный `REST` - без вопросов Retrofit. Если тупо постом гоняете данные туда-сюда, то проще `OkHttp`. И то и другое имеет как синхронный вид запросов, так и асинхронный. Разницы особо нет, в асинхронном чуть меньше писать. И там, и там 2 коллбэка на успешный результат запроса и провальный.

Основные данные у вас приходят скорее всего в виде `JsonArray`. Если не охота плодить лапшу, то лучше всего их сразу превращать в `ArrayList<YourObjectType>`. Сделать это проще всего через `GSON` библиотеку. Она в общем-то по умолчанию используется в `Retrofit`. Всегда можно сделать то же самое в `OkHttp`. Можно распарсить стандартными средствами, будет чуть дольше, результат будет тем же.

Полученный `ArrayList<YourObjectType>` передается в кастомный адаптер для `RecyclerView`, создаете `ViewHolder` и по сути все.

[Пример работы с RecyclerView](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

[Пример работы с OkHttp](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html)

[Пример работы с Retrofit](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)

А теперь самое интересное. Стоит решить как именно приложение должно узнавать о том, что у вас там какие-то новости появились. Вариантов 3:

1) Пользователь открывает приложение - данные подгружаются с сервера постом.

2) У приложения есть сервис, который периодически получает данные с сервера постом. Периодически - либо в какое-то конкретное время, либо раз в какой-то промежуток времени. Плюс перед первым вариантом - можно выкидывать Push уведомление.

3) У приложения есть сервис, который сокетом получает данные о получении новости. Плюсы - моментально. Минусы - вам придется еще создавать сервер, который будет получать данные с сайта и пихать их всем подключенным клиентам. А еще из минусов это адовое пожирание заряда аккумулятора пользователя.

**Update**

Из всех вариантов я рекомендую сделать первый вариант, он все равно нужен и он все равно пригодится. Прикрутить сервис всегда успеется.

Еще из важного, что сразу не учел - необходимо пользование `SQLite` база данных для сохранения уже открытых новостей. В противном случае без интернета приложение станет уж совсем бесполезным.

[Пример сервиса](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

[Пример SQLite](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/android-sqlite.php)

Comment: Спасибо, довольно таки исчерпывающий ответ, но вот касательно 3-х вариантов получения новости(а именно первых двух), возможно и тут найдутся дополнительно советы(примеры вообще б супер).

Comment: @Inkognito обновил пост